# Random or Frequency Sweep

Tags: resonance

Given a resonator. I'd like to excite it but I only know a range of possible resonance frequencies ($\pm 10\text{ Hz}$). What is the most effective way to excite my system?

1. Irradiating my system with one random frequence?
2. Irradiating with a frequency sweep?

How does this depend on the resonator?

Comment: Are you trying to determine the resonant frequency? What capabilities does your exciter have? What does "effective" mean to you? Least time, fewest steps, ... I would excite with white noise and look at the response - it will be at resonance. But that requires me to have a white noise generator. And how well you can measure the response depends on the Q of the system. So many variables...

Comment: @DanielSank 1. No; 2. You choose out of two: One with a fixed randomly chosen frequency frmo the range and the range sweeping one. 3. Effective mean more energy in my resonator over time and at all; 4. A White Noise Exciter is not applicable. Did I reduce some of the variables? What is the "Q of my system"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Q of a system tells you over what range of frequencies it can be excited, and how much "amplification" you get at resonance.

If you have a system with a high Q (narrow bandwidth) and you drive it with an off-resonance frequency, you will get barely any response. If instead you sweep the frequencies, then at the time you hit the frequency "on the nose" you will get a big response that will keep going after the stimulus has moved to a new frequency.

An intuitive example of this is a bell. When you hit a bell, you are in essence exciting it with many different frequencies (a delta function contains all frequencies - a short strike will contain lots of frequencies). The bell the continues to ring for some time.

If instead you played a note in the vicinity of the bell, you might not excite any resonance at all.

Now the actual calculation is a bit more complex than this: is the average power transferred greater if you hit the system many times at many different frequencies? The answer is probably "no" - because many individual excitations at different frequencies will average to the same thing as a single sweep. But if you have only one chance and you want to excite resonance, sweeping is the way to go.

Comment: How would the differential equation for harmonic oscillator look like, when driven with a sweep. Like this $    \frac{\mathrm{d}^2x}{\mathrm{d}t^2} + 2\zeta\omega_0\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t} + \omega_0^2 x = \frac{1}{m} F_0 \sin(\omega(t) t), $, with a varying $\omega(t)$? E.g. $\omega(t)=x_{Trianlge}(t)+\omega_0$...

Comment: @draks... That looks about right. Don't ask me to solve that equation...

Comment: Don't neglect the possibility of nonlinearity in your resonantor. Most real systems are nonlinear and although they might exhibit a spectral width about a resonant frequency that appears to be 'Q' or equivalently the effects of linear damping, a good part of the spectral broadening might be due to nonlinear distortion. Nonlinear systems can also lead to subsequent sidebands and subharmonics that are not characteristic of linear systems. One test is to vary the amplitude of your excitation. If the response does not vary linearly, the system is nonlinear. And as Floris reccomended...

Comment: ... sweeping a sine wave is a better choice in the case your resonantor is nonlinear. But broadband excitation white noise or colored noise can also have benefits like calculating the coherance function along with your spectrum. Coherance gives you an indication of the spectral quality of your measurement, and can also be used to detect nonlinearity.